# Edit parameter description for Django REST swagger and other issues

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I. I'm new to using Django REST Swagger for API documentation. I'm trying to understand how to edit a) 'Implementation Notes' and b) parameter descriptions. Image below -

[image]

Here's my viewset for the 'Crash' model.

```
class CrashViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
retrieve: Get a single Crash instance

list: Get a list of all Crashes
"""
queryset = Crash.objects.all()
serializer_class = CrashSerializer
filter_backends = (SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,)
search_fields = ('crash_id','crash_hr_short_desc','urb_area_short_nm','fc_short_desc',
                 'hwy_compnt_short_desc','mlge_typ_short_desc', 'specl_jrsdct_short_desc',
                 'jrsdct_grp_long_desc','st_full_nm','isect_st_full_nm','rd_char_short_desc',
                 'isect_typ_short_desc','crash_typ_short_desc','collis_typ_short_desc',
                 'rd_cntl_med_desc','wthr_cond_short_desc','rd_surf_short_desc','lgt_cond_short_desc',
                 'traf_cntl_device_short_desc','invstg_agy_short_desc','crash_cause_1_short_desc',
                 'crash_cause_2_short_desc','crash_cause_3_short_desc','pop_rng_med_desc','rd_cntl_med_desc')
filter_fields = ('ser_no','cnty_id','alchl_invlv_flg','crash_day_no','crash_mo_no','crash_yr_no','crash_hr_no',
                'schl_zone_ind','wrk_zone_ind','alchl_invlv_flg','drug_invlv_flg','crash_speed_invlv_flg',
                'crash_hit_run_flg',)
ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

I have made some edits to the DocString but don't quite understand how to proceed so as to get a more thorough descriptions of the endpoints and their fields. I tried going through [the Django REST Swagger tutorial](https://marcgibbons.com/django-rest-swagger/) but I'm not given any direction on how to format the DOCSTRING. What's the best way to do this?

---

II. Another minor issue is that I want to get rid of the 'Django Login' button since this is public API. How do I do this? [image]

---

III. What are some best practices for API documentation?